# Difference between weights and prior in rpart and how to use them

Tags: r, rpart

I have a question about the "weights" and "prior" in R's rpart function. 
This question has been asked before [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-July/135993.html), but the answer doesn't quite make sense.

Currently I have very unbalanced data where the target is only 0.0066% of the whole dataset, which has over 2 million rows. I want to know if either the "weights" or the "prior" can help me with this biased dataset, and how they would be used.

I tried oversampling the target and downsampling the noise and then producing an ensemble of my predictions, but I did not achieved the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

I see two questions here.

#### 1) What is the difference between `weights` and `parms` in `rpart`?

If you look at the code, `weights` argument is passed to the `model.frame` object, so it should be applied towards each observation of your dataset, just like in `lm`.

```
if (is.data.frame(model)) {
    m <- model  ## <---- m is defined here
    model <- FALSE
}
else {
    indx <- match(c("formula", "data", "weights", "subset"), 
        names(Call), nomatch = 0L)
    if (indx[1] == 0L) 
        stop("a 'formula' argument is required")
    temp <- Call[c(1L, indx)]
    temp$na.action <- na.action
    temp[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)  ## <---- passed to model.frame
    m <- eval.parent(temp)
}
Terms <- attr(m, "terms")
if (any(attr(Terms, "order") > 1L)) 
    stop("Trees cannot handle interaction terms")
Y <- model.response(m)
wt <- model.weights(m)  ## <---- used as observation weights
```

On the other hand, `parms` is for the class weights, which deals with unbalanced class size. I believe this is what you are looking for.

#### 2) How to use the `parms` argument?

If you look at the description of `parms`:

> For classification splitting, the list can contain any of: the vector of prior probabilities (component prior), ...

Hence, you want to store your prior probability vector in a list with name "prior". **The order of probability should be exactly the same as the output of `levels(data$y)`**, where `y` indicates your response variable. For example, you might want to try something like the following:

```
fit <- rpart(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = data, parms = list(prior = c(0.000066, 1 - 0.000066)))
```

Comment: how to calculate the prior values for more, i.e. example 3 classes ? @mark, i cant write comments and at the moment i'm not able to finish the registration to ask a new question, after clicking the confirmation link in email and setting my password it tells me that i'm already registered. so maybe one of the mods can make this a comment?

Comment: @guest12345 You could just write 3 probabilities to the prior? e.g., `parms = list(prior = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))`